# Shiny cicerone tour across different tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if it were possible to use the cicerone package to create a guided tour that spans multiple tabs, starting from a guide button located on an "About" tab, as per the script below.  I can only get a tour to work on one tab so far.  However, I have been asked to use a tour to show the connection between plots on different tabs of a shiny app.

If Cicerone is not the answer, could someone please suggest a good alternative?

Btw, I don't have sufficient reputation to create a cicerone tag.  If someone else would, that would be great.

```
library(shiny)
library(cicerone)



#Cicerone guide
guide <- Cicerone$
  new(allow_close = FALSE)$
  step(
    "nobs1",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 1"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button1",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the first plot"
  )$
  step(
    "hist1",
    "Histogram",
    "The first histogram appears here."
  )$
  step(
    "nobs2",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 1"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button2",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the second plot"
  )$
  step(
    "hist2",
    "Histogram",
    "The second histogram appears here."
  )





#####################################
#UI

ui <- 
  
  shinyUI(
    navbarPage("One tour with Cicerone across different tabs",
               
               ###########################             
               
               tabPanel("About",
                        "In this app you can input data and try out different plots.",
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$br(),
                        "If you need help, take the tour below.",
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$br(),
                        use_cicerone(),
                        actionButton("guide", "Take the tour")


                        ),

               ###########################             
               
               
               ########################################################
               
               tabPanel("Plots",
                        
                        #######################################
                        
                        tabsetPanel(
                            
                            
                            tabPanel("Plot 1",
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       numericInput("nobs1", "Observations", min = 50, max = 200, value = 20),
                                       
                                       actionButton("submit_button1", "Submit observations")
                                       
                                      
                                       
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(
                                       plotOutput("hist1")
                                       
                                     )
                                     
                                     
                            ), #closes tab panel Plot 1
                            
                            tabPanel("Plot 2",
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       numericInput("nobs2", "Observations", min = 50, max = 200, value = 20),
                                       
                                       actionButton("submit_button2", "Submit observations")
                                       
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(
                                       plotOutput("hist2")
                                       
                                     )
                                     
                                     
                            ) #closes tab panel Plot 2
                            
                            
                            
                          )#closes tabset panel
                        
                        
               )#closes tab panel
               
               
               
               
               
    ) #closes navBarPage
    
  ) #closes shinyUI


#####################################
#SERVER

server <- function(input, output){
  
  guide$
    init()$
    start()
  
  dat1 <- eventReactive(input$submit_button1, {
    runif(input$nobs1)
  })
  
  dat2 <- eventReactive(input$submit_button2, {
    runif(input$nobs2)
  })
  
  output$hist1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(dat1())
  })
  
  output$hist2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(dat2())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$guide, {
    guide$start()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You should submit your own answer. This will help track SO community which questions remain unanswered :) Your post helped me by the way so thank you.

Comment: Your code does not work. It doesn't change the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is funny how you can head scratch for days over a problem and you type a stack question and you suddenly find an answer.

I have figured out how to navigate the tabs with a guide as per the below.  Now I am left with the smaller question of how do I activate the tour only when the guide button is clicked (i.e. not upon loading of the page).:

```
#New guide

#Cicerone guide
guide <- Cicerone$
  new()$
  step(
    "[data-value='Plots']",
    "Plots",
    "Click on the Plots tab to see available plots",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "nobs1",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 1"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button1",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the first plot"
  )$
  
  step(
    "hist1",
    "Histogram",
    "The first histogram appears here."
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='Plot 2']",
    "Plot 2",
    "Click on the Plot 2 tab to try the next plot",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "nobs2",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 2"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button2",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the second plot"
  )$
  step(
    "hist2",
    "Histogram",
    "The second histogram appears here."
  )
```

and altogether now:

```
library(shiny)
library(cicerone)



#Cicerone guide
guide <- Cicerone$
  new()$
  step(
    "[data-value='Plots']",
    "Plots",
    "Click on the Plots tab to see available plots",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "nobs1",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 1"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button1",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the first plot"
  )$
  
  step(
    "hist1",
    "Histogram",
    "The first histogram appears here."
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='Plot 2']",
    "Plot 2",
    "Click on the Plot 2 tab to try the next plot",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "nobs2",
    "Observations",
    "Number of observations to draw distribution for plot 2"
  )$
  step(
    "submit_button2",
    "Submit Data",
    "Hit the button after you've set the number of observations for the second plot"
  )$
  step(
    "hist2",
    "Histogram",
    "The second histogram appears here."
  )





#####################################
#UI

ui <- 
  
  shinyUI(
    navbarPage("One tour with Cicerone across different tabs",
               
               ###########################             
               
               tabPanel("About",
                        "In this app you can input data and try out different plots.",
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$br(),
                        "If you need help, take the tour below.",
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$br(),
                        use_cicerone(),
                        actionButton("guide", "Take the tour")
                        
                        
               ),
               
               ###########################             
               
               
               ########################################################
               
               tabPanel("Plots",
                        
                        #######################################
                        
                        tabsetPanel(
                          
                          
                          tabPanel("Plot 1",
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                     numericInput("nobs1", "Observations", min = 50, max = 200, value = 20),
                                     
                                     actionButton("submit_button1", "Submit observations")
                                     
                                     
                                     
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                     plotOutput("hist1")
                                     
                                   )
                                   
                                   
                          ), #closes tab panel Plot 1
                          
                          tabPanel("Plot 2",
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                     numericInput("nobs2", "Observations", min = 50, max = 200, value = 20),
                                     
                                     actionButton("submit_button2", "Submit observations")
                                     
                                     
                                     
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                     plotOutput("hist2")
                                     
                                   )
                                   
                                   
                          ) #closes tab panel Plot 2
                          
                          
                          
                        )#closes tabset panel
                        
                        
               )#closes tab panel
               
               
               
               
               
    ) #closes navBarPage
    
  ) #closes shinyUI


#####################################
#SERVER

server <- function(input, output){
  
  guide$
    init()$
    start()
  
  dat1 <- eventReactive(input$submit_button1, {
    runif(input$nobs1)
  })
  
  dat2 <- eventReactive(input$submit_button2, {
    runif(input$nobs2)
  })
  
  output$hist1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(dat1())
  })
  
  output$hist2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(dat2())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$guide, {
    guide$start()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```